# Почему нельзя использовать условные логические операторы при создании предиката в короткой нотации тернарным оператором?

Tags: c#, тернарный-оператор, предикат

Столкнулся со странным поведением: при создании предиката тернарным оператором нельзя использовать условные логические операторы в короткой нотации. Возникает ошибка компилятора [CS0173](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0173). Скорее всего код лучше объяснит что имеется ввиду.

```cs
public class Account {
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

// Так можно,
Predicate<Account> predicate = x => x.IsActive && !x.IsDeleted;

// а так нет,
Predicate<Account> predicate = onlyDeleted
  ? x => x.IsDeleted
  : x => x.IsActive && !x.IsDeleted;
// Ошибка CS0173
// Не удается определить тип условного выражения,
// так как неявного преобразования между
// "лямбда-выражение" и "лямбда-выражение" не существует.

// но так тоже можно.
Predicate<Account> predicate = onlyDeleted
  ? x => x.IsDeleted
  : new Predicate<Account>(x => x.IsActive && !x.IsDeleted);
```

Используется Visual Studio 2019 версии 16.4.2.

---

Интересует почему так происходит? Может имеются какие-либо другие варианты?

---

Теперь (в C# 9) работает.

Comment: На английском SO есть ответ на ваш вопрос ([ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263177/6468198))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как у лямбды нет однозначного типа

```
x => x.IsDeleted
```

может трактоваться и как `Func<A,B>` и как `Expression<Func<A,B>>` компилятор не всегда может сам вывести необходимый тип. (именно поэтому нельзя писать `var a = x => x.IsDeleted`)

В простых случаях - обычное присваивание - это работает, в случае же с тернарным оператором, идет попытка определения типа обеих ветвей. Так как ни в одной из ветвей нет явного типа, компилятор не может вывести общий тип, который вернет тернарный оператор и поэтому ничего не делает .

В случае указания типа хотя бы для одной из ветвей все начинает работать.